# Twilio Next and Previous URI Usage

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I'm getting Twilio's next and previous page URI's via the PHP helper library like this..

```
$prevpage = $client->messages->page()->getPreviousPageUrl();
$nextpage = $client->messages->page()->getNextPageUrl();
```

What is the suggested way to load the data from these URI's, using the PHP Helper Library?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You don't have to use the URLs if you don't want to. You can just call `nextPage()` or `previousPage()` and you will fetch the next/previous page:

```
$prevpage = $client->messages->page()->previousPage();
$nextpage = $client->messages->page()->nextPage();
```

Let me know if that helps at all.